# accessing the "local" variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
def get(self):
    if self.request.get('fmt')=='json':
        KeyofQuestion = self.request.path[1:]
        QuestionText = Question.get_by_key_name(KeyofQuestion).question
        AnswersQuery = Question.get_by_key_name(KeyofQuestion).answers_collection
        a=[]
        Jsonobject = {'Question':QuestionText}
        for each in AnswersQuery:
            a = a.append(each.answer)
```

Hey, i am just confused that when I run the codes above, I got an error that says, Nonetype variable:a doesnt have method append, but I declared the a as a list before I called and they are inside the same function "get", so I assumed they are all treated as local variables. How come it cant map it?  Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning `None` to `a`. Change this:

```
a = a.append(each.answer)
```

to:

```
a.append(each.answer)
```

Comment: or just `a=[each.answer for each in AnswersQuery]`